# Getting input for character arrays

Tags: c

I was coding a program to find the longest common sub-sequence today and I was getting the elements of the each sequence into a character array. but I ran into a little problem. I used a for loop to get the elements but not matter how high I set the number of iterations the loop should execute it always terminated after 5 iterations. The array into which the data was being input was an array of size 10 so there were no issues with the array size. I coded a small test program to check and even in the test program the for loops that get data for a character array always terminate after 5 iterations . Why ?( I am forced to use turbo c++ in my lab)

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
     int i;
     char s[10];
     for(i=0;i<10;i++)
     scanf("%c",&a[i]);
 }
```

The above code was the test program.for loop terminated after 5 iterations here too !

Comment: *sigh* at least try to compile the code before you post it. also, the loop definitely doesn't terminate after 5 iterations, you should have put some trace message there to see it :/

Comment: ok i did compile it. and i tried displaying i after ever scanf statement. but it just kept incrementing twice .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newline characters (`'\n'`) are characters too.  If you type `H`, `<return>`, `e`, `<return>`, `l`, `<return>`, `l`, `<return>`, `o`, `<return>`, they you've entered 10 characters.

Answer (score 1):

It's a much better idea to just read the entire "array" as a single string, all at once:

```
char s[10];
fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, you're pressing `return` after each character? The `scanf()` call will read those too...